# Accuracy of same validation dataset differs between last epoch and after fit

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

The following code gives a log ending with

```
Epoch 19/20
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 473ms/step - loss: 1.4018 - accuracy: 0.8750 - val_loss: 1.8656 - val_accuracy: 0.8900
Epoch 20/20
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 444ms/step - loss: 0.5904 - accuracy: 0.8750 - val_loss: 2.1255 - val_accuracy: 0.8700
get_dataset: validation
Found 1000 files belonging to 2 classes.
Using 100 files for validation.
4/4 [==============================] - 1s 81ms/step
eval acc: 0.81
```

My question is:

Why is the `val_accuracy` after the last epoch (0.87) different from the `eval acc` (0.81) after the fit?

In my code, I try to use the **same dataset** for the validation of each epoch during fit and the additional validation afterwards.

[*Update 1, 2022-07-19*:

1. Obviously, the two accuracy calculations don't really use the same data. How can I debug which data is actually used?
   [*Update 3, 2022-07-20*: I have followed the data into TensorFlow. The last thing I see is that in `Model.evaluate` (during `fit`) and `Model.predict` the `x.filenames` are equal. I did not manage to debug much further, because soon in `quick_execute` the `__inference_test_function_248219` resp. the `__inference_predict_function_231438` are evaluated outside Python, and the arguments are tensors with `dtype=resource`, whose contents I cannot see.]
2. I have deliberately removed my class balancing code to keep my example small. I know that this makes the accuracies less useful, but I don't care about that for now.
3. Note that `get_dataset('validation')` is only called once at the beginning of the fit, not at each epoch.
4. I have now also set `max_queue_size=0, use_multiprocessing=False, workers=0` (as seen [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/11878), found via [this related SO question about TensorFlow 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55605302/the-accuracy-that-the-fit-generator-outputs-in-keras-differs-from-the-manually-c)), but this did not make the accuracies equal.

]

Code:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image_dataset_from_directory
    
inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(224, 224, 3))
base_model = tf.keras.applications.ResNet50(weights='imagenet', include_top=False)
base_output = base_model(inputs)
base_model.trainable = False
out = Flatten(name='flat')(base_output)
out = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(out)
model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=out)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

def get_dataset(subset):
    print('get_dataset:', subset)
    return image_dataset_from_directory(
        'data-nodup-1000',
        labels="inferred",
        label_mode='binary',
        color_mode="rgb",
        image_size=(224, 224),
        shuffle=True,
        seed=1,
        validation_split=0.1,
        subset=subset,
        crop_to_aspect_ratio=False,
    )

model.fit(
    get_dataset('training'),
    steps_per_epoch=1,
    epochs=20,
    validation_data=get_dataset('validation'),
    max_queue_size=0,
    use_multiprocessing=False,
    workers=0,
)

val_dataset = get_dataset('validation')
true_class = tf.concat([y for x, y in val_dataset], axis=0)
pred = model.predict(val_dataset)
pred_class = pred >= .5
print('eval acc:', accuracy_score(true_class, pred_class))
```

[*Update 2, 2022-07-19*:
I can also reproduce the behavior with the deprecated `ImageDataGenerator`, using

```py
from tensorflow.keras.applications.resnet50 import preprocess_input
from keras_preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    preprocessing_function=preprocess_input,
    validation_split=0.1,
)

def get_dataset(subset):
    print('get_dataset:', subset)
    return datagen.flow_from_directory(
        'data-nodup-1000',
        class_mode='binary',
        target_size=(224, 224),
        shuffle=True,
        seed=1,
        subset=subset,
    )
```

and

```py
true_class = val_dataset.labels
```

]

[*Update 4, 2022-07-21*: Note that deactivating shuffling of validation data by setting `shuffle=(subset == 'training')` makes the two validation accuracies equal. This is not a workaround, however, because the validation set then consists only of class 1, since `flow_from_directory` doesn't do stratification.
]

My environment:

- I am using all up-to-date libraries, like tensorflow 2.9.1 and sklearn 1.1.1 (via `pip-compile -U`).
- The folder `data-nodup-1000` contains one subfolder with 113 files of class 0, and one subfolder with 887 files of class 1.

Comment: Validation data doesn't affect performance, that's for you to fine-tune with. Also 113 class 0 and 887 class 1 will naturally have bias.

Comment: @Djinn I know that. My question is: Why are the two described accuracies different? It seems as if they were computed on different data, although I tried to get both of them computed on the same validation dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now [found out](https://discuss.tensorflow.org/t/tf-data-dataset-varies-at-re-iteration-manual-reset-possible/11695/9?u=robert.pollak) that in TensorFlow 2.9.1 `model.predict` uses the *second iteration* of the dataset, which is shuffled differently than the first iteration!
It even uses the second iteration when I directly call `model.predict(get_dataset('validation'))`!

Therefore, the entries of `true_class` and `pred` do not match.

Switching to TensorFlow 2.10.0-rc3 and its `tf.keras.utils.split_dataset` makes the accuracies equal.

Here's the updated code:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image_dataset_from_directory
    
inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(224, 224, 3))
base_model = tf.keras.applications.ResNet50(weights='imagenet', include_top=False)
base_output = base_model(inputs)
base_model.trainable = False
out = Flatten(name='flat')(base_output)
out = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(out)
model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=out)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

dataset = image_dataset_from_directory(
    'data-synthetic',
    labels="inferred",
    label_mode='binary',
    color_mode="rgb",
    image_size=(224, 224),
    shuffle=True,
    seed=1,
    crop_to_aspect_ratio=False,
)
train_dataset, val_dataset = tf.keras.utils.split_dataset(dataset, right_size=0.1)

model.fit(
    train_dataset,
    steps_per_epoch=1,
    epochs=20,
    validation_data=val_dataset,
    max_queue_size=0,
    use_multiprocessing=False,
    workers=0,
)

true_class = tf.concat([y for x, y in val_dataset], axis=0)
pred = model.predict(val_dataset)
pred_class = pred >= .5
print('eval acc:', accuracy_score(true_class, pred_class))
```

which correctly yields:

```
Epoch 19/20
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 438ms/step - loss: 0.4426 - accuracy: 0.9062 - val_loss: 0.4658 - val_accuracy: 0.8800
Epoch 20/20
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 444ms/step - loss: 2.1619 - accuracy: 0.8438 - val_loss: 0.5886 - val_accuracy: 0.8900
4/4 [==============================] - 1s 87ms/step
eval acc: 0.89
```

Answer (score -1):

there are a few points about your data which causes this:

- First, your data is highly imbalanced (8 to 1 label ratio) which makes the model rather overfit and the CV estimate inaccurate.
- Second, in the `get_dataset` function, the `shuffle` is set to `True` so every time you call the `get_dataset()`, it shuffles your data, and because (1) Your validation set is very small and (2) your train/val split is not stratified over your labels, the validation metrics would vary a lot due to this shuffling.

Suggestions to solve this:

1. call the `get_dataset()` only once for train and val dataset before fitting the model and save them as variables. and if there is no sequential order in your data, maybe set `shuffle=False`.
2. (optional) If possible make your dataset more balanced by techniques such as data augmentation, over-/under-sampling, etc.

```
def get_dataset(subset):
    return image_dataset_from_directory(
        'data-nodup-1000',
        labels="inferred",
        label_mode='binary',
        color_mode="rgb",
        image_size=(224, 224),
        shuffle=False,
        seed=0,
        validation_split=0.1,
        subset=subset,
        crop_to_aspect_ratio=False,
    )

train_dataset = get_dataset('training')
val_dataset = get_dataset('validation')

model.fit(
    train_dataset,
    steps_per_epoch=1,
    epochs=20,
    validation_data=val_dataset,
)


true_class = tf.concat([y for x, y in val_dataset], axis=0)
pred = model.predict(val_dataset)
pred_class = pred >= .5
print('eval acc:', accuracy_score(true_class, pred_class))
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I have deliberately removed my class balancing code from this example to keep it small. I know that this makes accuracy values less meaningful, but I don't care about that for debugging here. Note that the arguments to the `model.fit` call are evaluated only once before calling the `fit` function, so your code is equivalent to mine, and testing it shows exactly the same problem: validation accuracy of the last epoch is for unknown reason different than after the fit.

Comment: Also, disabling shuffling breaks my validation data (since there is no stratification) and would be just a workaround instead of an answer to my question.